# Eliminar espaço no name de um input

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helpers, asp.net-mvc-helper

É o seguinte, estou fazendo um foreach desta maneira .

```
int count = 1;
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <input name="itemId_@count" value="@item.ProdutoId" type="hidden">

        count++;
    }
```

O problema é que no processamento o underline é processado junto, e eu precisava que ele não fosse processado, se eu fizer desta maneira.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <input name="itemId@count" value="@item.ProdutoId" type="hidden">

    count++;
}
```

O @count não é reconhecido.

Preciso de uma alternativa para poder referenciar o @count sem precisar usar espaços ou caracteres. Ou algum pequeno script que limpe o espaço, mas não faço ideia se isso é possível.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Remover espaço de um name em um form](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303439/remover-espa%c3%a7o-de-um-name-em-um-form)

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar chaves `()` junto ao arroba `@`.

```
@{
    int count = 1;
    foreach (var item in Model})
    {
        <input name="itemId@(count)" value="@item.ProdutoId" type="hidden">

        count++;
    }
}
```